# Is it possible to use mathematical functions in columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, create-table

Is it possible to make columns in my mysql project a little bit more "inteligent"?

I mean that I want make it look like in excel project. For example I have columns A and B where I can put some numbers and column C where I want have added these 2 columns like this:

```
Column A | Column B | Column C

    2          5         7 
    8          1         9
    4          4         8
```

In excel I'm just creating math method like: "=A+B", but is it possible to do this here in mysql ?

Thanks,
SM

Answer (score 2):

If you are running MySQL 5.7 or higher, you can use a [computed column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

```
create table mytable (
    cola int,
    colb int,
    colc int as (cola + colb)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Database Triggers if you need to add complex logic. Using these triggers you will be able to add any code you need when your columns are updated, inserted or deleted.

You can find more information here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html